# How to Customize Order Details Page for Customers

Tags: magento2, theme, template, sales-order, magento-2.2.1

I'm trying to customize the order detail page that the customer see in his/her account.

What I did is that I copied:

```
vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/templates/order/view.phtml
```

Into:

```
app/design/frontend/CompanyName/ThemeName/Magento_Sales/view/frontend/templates/order/view.phtml
```

And added some test modifications in there but nothing showed up on the website and it continues to use the original `view.phtml`

I tried clearing all cache and deploying static content with no luck.

When I enable `Template Path Hints for Storefront` in the admin and access the order details page, it's still showing that it's using the original `view.phtml` and not the customized one

Can you please help me with this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When overriding templates your files should be in :

> app/design/frontend/CompanyName/ThemeName/Magento_Sales/templates/order/view.phtml

you should not add **view/frontend/** folders. All your templates should be in

```
app/design/frontend/CompanyName/ThemeName/Magento_Sales/templates/
```

Answer (score 0):

It always suggested that we must inherit the patent theme if it is created than you must work in child themes or if it is not created `WE MUST CREATE` a child them

To inherit the parent or Magento core theme follow [Theme inheritance](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-inherit.html) .

Once we go through the above document we can customize any page.Rule appies to all the phtml files.

You already know how to debug as mentioned that you found the path still i am sharing this link [How to debug the theme](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/themes/debug-theme.html)

Magento 2 [Basic layouts](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/layout-overview.html)

Comment: Thanks for the pointer and the links provided. However, I'm already working on a child theme that I have created based on another premium theme that I have bought.

Comment: happy to hear , always available to help.